# Does "off" mean "beginning with" in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

I am wondering what does "off" mean in following sentence:

> *"This year, production is off to a slow start; only five vehicles are manufactured each hour."*

Does it mean that the production is beginning with a slow start? Or does it mean something else?

Thank you in advance, and have a great day.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81714/what-does-off-to-mean.

Answer (score 1):

*Off* here is being used in adjective sense 2a from [www.m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off):

> 2a :  started on the way

You could consider it to be short for "moving off of the starting line of a race track" (because the race has begun).

In fact, the most idiomatic expression for this usage generally IS at a race track, when the race starts; you'll often hear the announcer say "Aaaaand they're off!"

So when you're *off to a slow start*, it means you have begun something, but are doing poorly in comparison to either your opponents or to your expectations.  (Conversely, you might "get off to a *good start* or a *fast start*" if you are doing better than expected at the beginning of your effort.)